# jQuery Keyup function not working

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I am using jQuery Keyup function but its not working for me

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery.noConflict();
          $("firstName").keyup(function(){
             alert("first Name");
         });   

</script>

<apex:form id="PrimaryTab"> 
<div>
 <label for="inputdefault">First Name</label>
 <apex:inputField value="{!le.firstName}" styleClass="form-control id="firstName" required="true"/>
</div>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Check browser console if you getting any jQuery errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using JQuery before declaring `jQuery.noConflict();`

Also, this statement replace the `$` variable by `jQuery`.

And finally, as Rahul just said in his answer, Salesforce add a prefix to the ids declared on your VF page.

So you should use:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery("input[id$='firstName']").keyup(function(){
             alert("first Name");
         });   
        });

</script>
```

Comment: Ah didn't catch jQuery.noConflict(), thanks!

Comment: Another thing missing is closing ready function.

Comment: Yes you're right! I missed that.

Comment: I believe class selectors are much better performance than ends with selectors, fyi.

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson. I didn't know that. But what bother me is that class selectors are designed to be applied on multiple elements. Ids are designed to be unique.

Comment: Yeah but then you go and apply an `ends with` selector and it's no longer unique. You can have many ids that all end with `'firstName'`.

Comment: You're right. Do you know if there is another way than a class selector and the ends with selector on ids?

Answer (score 4):

In Salesforce, for visualforce components the HTML Id gets generated [dynamically](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm).

So you have to use [ends with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) or use a class which is cleaner.

In your example, Try replacing:

```
$("firstName")
```

With:

```
$("input[id$='firstName']")
// or with 
$("[id$='firstName']")
```

---

Your script should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j("firstName").keyup(function(){
            alert("first Name");
        });   
    });
</script>
```

Refer [this documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) to learn proper of use of noConflict() method.

---

**Issues with your code**:

1. Improper use of jQuery.noConflict() - thanks @Martin Lezer for identifying this.
2. Missed closing ready function - This is why indentation matters!
3. Accessing Visualforce component with starts with selector or use a CSS class.